# How to automatically choose elements to render to stargazer table

Tags: r, stargazer

I have saved three regressions (reg1, reg2, reg3) along with their standard errors (reg.se1, reg.se2, reg.se3) and cluster p values (reg.crp1, reg.crp2, reg.crp3). I want to create a chart with stargazer along the lines of:

`stargazer(list(reg1, reg2, reg3), se=list(reg.se1, reg.se2, reg.se3), p=list(reg.crp1, reg.crp2,reg.crp3))`

This works well but I need to add 30 more regressions, and I was wondering if there was a way to create a loop so that I can do it automatically instead of having to add the extra 30 regressions manually?

Thank you very much,

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need a loop. Some creative string matching for `ls()` should be enough. I have used `stringr` library to accomplish this, but `?grep` in base R should work too.

```
library(stringr)

## this expression picks up everything that starts with "reg", but the fourth symbol is not '.'
coeflist <- ls()[!is.na(str_match(ls(), '^reg[^.;]+'))] 

## this expression picks up everything that starts with "reg.se"
selist <- ls()[!is.na(str_match(ls(), '^reg.se'))]

## this expression picks up everything that starts with "reg.crp"
pvallist <- ls()[!is.na(str_match(ls(), '^reg.crp'))]
```

Now you can create your stargazer table by

```
stargazer(coeflist, 
          selist,
          pvallist)
```

You need to make sure that your namespace does not have other elements that would have matching names.